# How to call Oauth APIs in Meteor for a single fixed account

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am interested in finding the simplest solution to calling an API through Meteor that is using Oauth, such as the google APIs.  It is for a single, fixed account to pull in data, rather than related to a logged in user account.

I found the following reference - http://blog.philcruz.com/2015/05/manually-getting-oauth-tokens-in-meteor.html

But am wondering if that is more complex than needed?  Any pointers to references or example code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oauth is not trivial, and so that link you provided does not look more complex than required.

However that workflow is the classic Oauth scenario, [as defined here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/faq):

> OAuth is an authentication protocol that allows users to approve
>   application to act on their behalf without sharing their
>   password.].

This is not the requirement you have.

First check to see if you can get by with using `Simple API access` [as defined here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication).

If not, look at these packages:

- [google-oauth-jwt](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-google-oauth-jwt)
- [google-api](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api)

I've never used either, however they appear to do what you require.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the google-oauth-jwt package was what I was looking for.  Apparently the concept I was looking for is "2 legged oauth" and works with Google service accounts.